# dpkg-reconfigure: dialog frontend sets up postfix successfully; non-interactive frontend fails

Tags: automation, dpkg, preseed, debian-stretch, debconf

*(N.B. In this question, a leading `#` indicates a root prompt, not a comment. Also, I have replaced the actual hostname with `<myhostname>`.)*

As the [`debconf (7)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debconf-doc/debconf.7.en.html) man-page states, `dpkg-reconfigure` can be invoked with any one of several front-ends, including the default ("**dialog**") interactive front-end, and the "**noninteractive**" frontend.

Am I right in thinking that running

```
# dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

to invoke the **dialog** front-end, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in response to each question, should be equivalent to running the following?

```
# dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive postfix
```

If so, then I do not understand the following discrepancy.

### Discrepancy

On a VPS freshly-populated with Debian 9 "Stretch" from my web host's image (which has postfix already installed), I preseed using `debconf-set-selections`:

```
# debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/destinations string <myhostname>"
# debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/mailbox_limit string 51200000"              
# debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/mailname string <myhostname>"    
# debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type select Internet Site"      
# debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/protocols select ipv4"                      
# debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/root_address string root"
```

If I then run `dpkg-reconfigure` interactively, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for every question, I get:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure postfix
dpkg-reconfigure postfix
Removing sqlite map entry from /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf
setting synchronous mail queue updates: false
Adding sqlite map entry to /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf
changing /etc/mailname to <myhostname>
setting myorigin
setting destinations: localhost
setting relayhost: 
setting mynetworks: 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
setting mailbox_size_limit: 51200000
setting recipient_delimiter: +
setting inet_interfaces: all
setting default_transport: smtp
setting relay_transport: smtp
setting inet_protocols: ipv4
WARNING: /etc/aliases exists, but does not have a root alias.

Postfix (main.cf) is now set up with the changes above.  If you need to make 
changes, edit /etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix 
configuration values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run 'service postfix reload'.

Running newaliases
```

Note that this does quite a lot, including setting `/etc/mailname`. At this point, postfix is ready to send mail.

By contrast, if I use the same VPS, starting again from a fresh image, and run the same commands except for invoking `dpkg-reconfigure` non-interactively, I get:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive postfix
Removing sqlite map entry from /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf
Adding sqlite map entry to /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf

Postfix (main.cf) configuration was not changed.  If you need to make changes, 
edit /etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix 
configuration values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run 'service postfix reload'.

Running newaliases
```

Note that this time, `/etc/mailname` was not set. Moreover, at this point, postfix is not ready to send mail and any attempts to make it do so result in bounces showing up in `/var/log/mail.log`.

### My questions

1. Was my initial assumption correct?
2. Is the above discrepancy a bug, or is it expected behaviour? (And if it is expected behaviour, then what was the rationale for this design choice?)

### Addendum

If I run `rm /etc/postfix/main.cf` before running `dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive postfix`, then `/etc/mailname` and `/etc/postfix/main.cf` both end up being created, and postfix ends up ready to send mail. This seems to be a viable workaround for the above failure, but it certainly violates the [Rule of Least Surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Unix_philosophy&oldid=807859553#Eric_Raymond%E2%80%99s_17_Unix_Rules) and feels as though it might be undefined behaviour that should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The postfix config files including `/etc/mailname` **CANNOT be changed** using `debconf-set-selections` and `dpkg-reconfigure` once the postfix config files have been written out. I burnt way too many hours trying to find out why...

**Why?**

`dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive` returns value [30 question skipped](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/debconf-doc/debconf-devel.7.en.html) for all questions (and uses the `debconf-set-selections` presets), the code in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/postfix.config` then does not set the debconf settings as changed and `/var/lib/dpkg/info/postfix.postinst` then does not write any postfix config.

**Workarounds?**

1. Good: The workaround as you found is to remove `/etc/postfix/main.cf` which forces `/var/lib/dpkg/info/postfix.postinst` to write out a new config for postfix which will include the new `debconf-set-selections` options.
2. Better: Alternative use `dpkg-reconfigure` in an interactive mode and confirm the questions, in which case `/var/lib/dpkg/info/postfix.config` marks the options as changed and `/var/lib/dpkg/info/postfix.postinst` writes out the changes.
3. Best: Alternative switch to managing `/etc/postfix/main.cf` etc options using [postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.1.html). (Likely a good idea to have a `echo "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type select No configuration" | debconf-set-selections` safety net)